# React failed to compile (Counter' is not defined )

Tags: reactjs

Can anyone help with this error:

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./src/components/counters.jsx
>
> Line 9:   'Counter' is not defined react/jsx-no-undef
>   Line 10:  'Counter' is not defined react/jsx-no-undef
>   Line 11:  'Counter' is not defined react/jsx-no-undef
>   Line 12:  'Counter' is not defined react/jsx-no-undef

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Counter extends Component {
  state = {
    count: 0
  };

  handleIncrement = product => {
    console.log(product);
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
  };

  doHandleIncrement = () => {
    this.handleIncrement({ id: 1 });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span className={this.getBadgeClasses()}>{this.formatCount()}</span>
        <button
          onClick={() => this.handleIncrement()}
          className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm"
        >
          Increment
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  getBadgeClasses() {
    let classes = "badge m-2 badge-";
    classes += this.state.count === 0 ? "warning" : "primary";
    return classes;
  }

  formatCount() {
    const { count } = this.state;
    return count === 0 ? "Zero" : count;
  }
}

export default Counter;
```

---

the other file:-> -> index.js

---

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import Counter from "./components/counter";
import Counters from "./components/counters";

ReactDOM.render(<Counter />, document.getElementById("root"));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

---

and other file -> -> counters.jsx

---

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Counters from "./counter";

class Counters extends Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Counter />
        <Counter />
        <Counter />
        <Counter />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Counters;
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the code that is giving rise to your error. Do you have another file where you use the `Counter` component without importing it first?

Comment: I ran your code and it works fine, you'll need to add more information

Comment: I added two files, maybe it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a simple typo in the import statements in your `counters.jsx`:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Counters from "./counter";
```

should be

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Counter from "./counter";
```